# Bootstrap off canvas to WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap off canvas to wordpress page to be visible on xs devices, like this example

> http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

My theme.js folder doesn't seems to be loaded in my wordpress page.

this is `page.php` code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <div class="col-md-9">

    <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs offcanvas-control" data-toggle="offcanvas">Sidebar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal"></span></button>
    </p>

     <?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="page-header">
         <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; else: ?>

  <div class="page-header">
         <h1>Oh no!</h1>
        </div>

        <p>No content is appearing for this page!</p>
     <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

this is `sidebar.php`

```
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar sidebar-offcanvas">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'page' ) ): ?>
    <h3>Widget Setup</h3>
    <p>Please add widgets to the page widget to have them display here</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

this is `theme.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) { 
    $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');  
    });
});
```

this is `functions.php`

```
// Load the Theme JS
function theme_js() {

    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_register_script( 'html5shiv', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js', '', '', false );
    wp_register_script( 'respond', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js', '', '', false );

    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'respond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery','bootstrap_js'), '', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Comment: You mean that `theme.js` is not enqueued? Does `bootstrap.js` get enqueued?

Comment: Yes. Theme js. is not enqueued but bootstrap.js is enqueued.

Comment: Strange thing... try renaming your script alias (because is the same as the function name used for enqueuing scripts - `theme_js`). Try this: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery','bootstrap_js'), '', true );`

Comment: In order to get some userful answers, try to edit your question in order to reflect the real issue: scripts don't get included in your wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser only loads this scripts

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
```